# Can't write to ULS

Tags: timer-jobs, uls

I have done some minor fixes to a timerjob, which writes to ULS after every step and error, but, for some reason after last deployment, it fails and is most confusing to me - doesn't write to ULS (even though from progress it is clearly seen that it should)

Comment: Do you have WSS_Log DB up and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the farm was on few machines, so the one on which the project was deployed, wasn't the one on which it worked

Comment: Take a look of SPJobLockType: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjoblocktype.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try these lines to write on the Log file:

```
SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("Your Category", TraceSeverity.High, EventSeverity.Information), TraceSeverity.High, "My log text");
```

Comment: Used practically same line, just with other constructor, in past it worked, now it doesn't

Comment: try to debug the job and see if u reach the log line

Comment: It should looking from progress, but problem is that in local machine it works fine, but in production machine it has this problem, so I can't use debugging either

Comment: try to put the lines after the Execute method declaration. (and after deployment remember to restart SP Timer Service)